# h2 на странице списка категорий

Tags: woocommerce

Подскажите, необходимо в Админка->Товары->Категории->Любая-выбранная-категория
добавить произвольное поле в которое будет записываться значение тега h2 и выводиться на странице.

Comment: вопрос-то какой?

Comment: Похоже вопрос звучит так, как создать кастом мета филд в категории?